# Use a word as a delimiter for cut command in linux without using awk

Tags: awk, cut

I'm trying to take the second segment of a line inside a file delimited by a certain string, and it would usually work something like `awk -F ':: My Delimiter ::' '{print $2}'`, but if I try to print `$2` it will print the second argument passed onto the function in which the `awk` command is located. Is there an alternate way to split a line by a delimiter and print a certain part of the result?

This is the exact line I'm having issues with:

```
for transaction in $(cat $1)
do
    echo "$transaction" | awk -F ':: My Delimiter ::' '{print $2}' >> testLog.data.out
done
```

Note: The delimiter would be exactly as described. :: My Delimiter ::

Comment: Can you show your code with some sample data that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: `f I try to print $2 it will print the second argument passed onto the function in which the awk command is located` Do you do `'{print $2}'` or `"{print $2}"`?

Comment: Sounds like theres a bug in your code where you call awk. Create and post  a [mcve] showing  complete (but minimal) code that can reproduce the problem plus concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can start trying to help you debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using cut, I think you should really use awk - your example `awk -F ':: My Delimiter ::' '{print $2}'` should work. If you printed the second arguments passed into the function containing that awk, then that means the `$2` was not inside single quotes - maybe you used double quotes? This wouldn't work (notice the double quotes):

```
awk -F ':: My Delimiter ::' "{print $2}"
```

But this would (your example):

```
awk -F ':: My Delimiter ::' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I updated the post with the line of code giving me trouble. For some reason it's still not working even with single quotes.

Comment: This comment made me look into the intput itself, and there appeared to be an issue with the cat. I was reading word by word instead of line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
echo ':: My Delimiter ::' | awk '{split($0,v,"My Delimiter"); print v[2]}' 


>>> echo 'ThisIsINeed0 My Delimiter ThisIsINeed1' | awk '{split($0,v," My Delimiter "); print v[1]}'
ThisIsINeed0
>>> echo 'ThisIsINeed0 My Delimiter ThisIsINeed1' | awk '{split($0,v," My Delimiter "); print v[2]}' 
ThisIsINeed1


>>> echo 'This Is I Need 0 My Delimiter This Is I Need 1' | awk '{split($0,v," My Delimiter "); print v[2]}' 
This Is I Need 1
>>> echo 'This Is I Need 0 My Delimiter This Is I Need 1' | awk '{split($0,v," My Delimiter "); print v[1]}' 
This Is I Need 0
```

Comment: Didn't work, it returns a blank space. And if I change it to ´v[1]´ it echoes the unformatted string, as in ignoring the awk

Comment: add space to your delimiter ?!?! May be get result.